# Dovecot not receiving mail while making use of vmail

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, dovecot

Below is my current vmail configuration.

```
auth_mechanisms = plain login
auth_username_format = %n

protocols = imap lmtp

# Search for valid users in /etc/passwd
userdb {
        driver = passwd
        args = uid=vmail gid=vmail home=/home/vmail/%u
}

# Fallback: Use plain old PAM to find user passwords
passdb {
        driver = pam
}

# Our mail for each user will be in ~/Mail, and the inbox will be ~/Mail/Inbox
# The LAYOUT option is also important because otherwise, the boxes will be `.Sent` instead of `Sent`.
mail_location = maildir:~/Mail:INBOX=~/Mail/Inbox:LAYOUT=fs
```

I have confirmed that if I use the regular user home directory I can receive email, but I cannot when using vmail.

Comment: What does your logs show?

Comment: @vidarlo Dovecot logs show nothing except successful imap login, I'm guessing it could be a problem with postfix? Not sure what though